# How to override method from model of module in yii?

Tags: php, yii

I want to use third party module in my several projects on yii.
For example module comments https://github.com/segoddnja/Comments-module

Usually need to do some changes in module for specific project.
If i need to use costom views, I will just copy them in to theme and modify.
How can I override method from php class, that located in module?
For example I want to modify method in model class. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i dont understand your problem , but simply locate the model file inside module directory inside application modules dir , override the method you want and feel free

Comment: can you give me an example of code, that allow me to extends from this model of module https://github.com/segoddnja/Comments-module/blob/master/models/Comment.php and override some method. where should I put file, that will extend that model?

Comment: @Mikola laviro if your module is already loaded on your main app, you can override model putting your custom model for example on protected/components/mymodel.php, using inheritance: class mymodel extends ModuleModel {....,}

Comment: Alejandro, you right, I can do that.
But how I can tell to all files in module, that they should use mymodel instead ModuleModel?
For example in mdule controlle will be next code "new Modulemodel". So mymodel will be not used?

Comment: @Mikola laviro in your other parts of your code you should use "new mymodel" instead "new ModuleModel"

Answer (score 0):

If you use this comments module repo a lot, but it seems that it just isn't the way you like (or need) it, then fork it!

Fork the repo, and edit the code the way you like it. Only you know how you need it to work. Add in your own custom functions, your own helpers, completely chop up the existing functions to work the way you want.

Remember, with OOP, your focus is reuse-ability. Create classes and functions that you can use on future projects.

If you have a function you use every time, but for 1 out of 10 projects you need to change it, then extend it. You can Extend your Class and override the function. So the only thing that would change, would be you would add in a new Class that extends your existing one, and ONLY has those few functions you need to override.

To extend it, You would just create a new file, in components as someone said. Unless you jacked up your main config, all files in the components dir are autoloaded. Just make sure the name of the file is the same as the class!

Just look at your CommentsModule for example. They extend CWebModule. CommentsModule has all the functions and variables that CWebModule has, but can have more functions/variables, or override ones defined in CWebModule. It essentially hijacked it.

```
Class CommentsModule Extends CWebModule{}
```